# Android Studio - Cannot deploy signed APK using Fabric plugin

Tags: android-studio, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to create a Beta distribution using Fabric plugin (v4.1.1) in Android Studio (v2.3.1).

I'm dragging the signed APK into the Fabric plugin window. After it, I am asked to select the testers, but the `Next` button does not work, even if I add some email address in the `Testers to Invite` edittext.

[image: Fabric Plugin]]

- Is there a way to check the logs of this plugin to see what's wrong with that button?
- Has anyone had this same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. It appears that you have no testers listed or selected for that release. You mentioned it happens even if you do, but I'd recommend adding some, click on Add and then see if Next starts working.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Same is happening for me. I'm on Fedora, latest Android Studio (stable channel). Others in my org (using OSX) can distribute via the plugin. I don't see any errors/etc. I'm also an Admin in Fabric, so I doubt it's permissions related.

Comment: @MikeBonnell ran AS from terminal, have a stacktrace for you https://pastebin.com/C9kQGn5e

Comment: Thanks @wes, it looks like a bug in the plugin based on the error; Which version of Fedora are you running and which version of Java?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I'm on Fedora 25 (fully updated, stock kernel/etc). I typically use the Oracle JDK, but this is a new machine, and it looks like AS is defaulting to the bundled JDK, which is OpenJDK. Here are the versions:  
<br>
<br>
`➜ java -version`  
`java version "1.8.0_131"`  
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)`  
`➜ /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version`  
`openjdk version "1.8.0_112-release"`  
`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)`  
`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b06, mixed mode)`

Comment: Thanks, will try to get a machine with a similar setup.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me as well. I have never had a problem before (same machine, same Android Studio). However, upon finding your question I realized that I had just installed some plugins. Specifically the plugin that messed the fabric plugin up is the Material Theme UI Fork. As soon as I disabled it I was able to press the Next button.

I don't know if the fault lies with the theme or Fabric.

So disable any non-default plugins and see if it helps.

Comment: Had the same issue, removing the Material Theme UI theme fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @Roisgoen can you please accept the answer in that case!

Comment: I didn't create the question, so I won't be able to accept it. @Leo